# Pass Parameters when loading external swf as2 when pressing corresponding button

Tags: flash, actionscript, load, actionscript-2

There is a code [here in this tutorial to load external swf](http://changesdone.com/index.php/posts/loading-an-external-swf-file-with-as2/) with as2:
The code is as follows:

```
var swfLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var loadingListener:Object = new Object();

swfLoader.addListener(loadingListener);

loadingBtn_mc.onRelease = function()
{
    swfLoader.loadClip("slides.swf",container_mc);
    this._visible = false;
};

loadingListener.onLoadStart = function(container:MovieClip):Void 
{
    trace("The MovieClip " + container + " started loading");
    loadingProgress_mc._x = 126;
    loadingProgress_mc._y = 135;
};

loadingListener.onLoadProgress = function(container:MovieClip, bytLoaded:Number, bytTotal:Number):Void 
{
    var percentageLoaded:Number = (bytLoaded / bytTotal) * 100;

    loadingProgress_mc.percentage_txt.text = String(Math.floor(percentageLoaded));

    trace("Loading progress = " + String(Math.floor(percentageLoaded)));
};

loadingListener.onLoadComplete = function(container:MovieClip):Void 
{
    trace("The MovieClip " + container + " has completed loading");
    loadingProgress_mc._x = -200;
};

loadingListener.onLoadInit = function(container:MovieClip):Void 
{
    trace("The MovieClip " + container + " has been initialized");
};

loadingListener.onLoadError = function(container:MovieClip, errorCode:String):Void 
{
    trace("Error loading the file. Error code = " + errorCode);
};
```

To unload swf (once loaded) I added:

```
    unloadingBtn_mc.onRelease = function()
{
    swfLoader.unloadClip(container_mc);
    //this._visible = false;
};
```

But How  how to pass a parameter to "slides.swf" in `swfLoader.loadClip("slides.swf",container_mc);` ?

[Here is the source file](http://changesdone.com/wp-content/zip/posts/2011/06/CD-loading-an-external-swf-file.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like...

```
swfLoader.loadClip("slides.swf?data1=12345&data2=67890",container_mc);
```

and then you should be able to access it like so (in slides.swf)...

```
var my_data1:String = _level0.data1;
var my_data2:String = _level0.data2;
```

Although, its been a while since I've done any AS2 :)

Comment: I used  `_root.the_variable = 'something';` Thank you